# How to refresh .desktop files in ~/.local/share/applications?

Tags: mate-desktop

I have created a new `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/application`. How do I make mate list it in Applications panel and in Run Application dialog (Alt+F2) without logging out and logging in again?

Comment: I'd try sending SIGHUP or SIGUSR1 to `mate-panel`. Just a guess though. I think you will have to restart your session.

Comment: @Bananguin SIGUSR1 worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$ killall -s SIGUSR1 mate-panel` - mate-panel restarts when I do it, and .desktop files are refreshed

Answer (score 1):

For xfce4 this work: "killall -USR1 xfce4-appfinder"